# JQGrid - ccur is undefined

Tags: jqgrid

I've done quite a bit of googling on this error but have had no luck.  I'm basically sending a JSON result to the jqGrid and getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting jsonReader : { repeatitems: false } in my jqGrid declaration got around this issue.